# yaml dump a python dictionary without quotes

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

when I try to dump a python dictionary to yaml file, I get results with quotes both keys and values.
For example I create a python dictonary:

```
d = { 'a': '1', 'b': '2' }
with open(attributes_file, "w") as fw:
   yaml.dump(dict_attributes, fw)
```

I get this output:

```
'a': '1'
'b': '2'
```

How to remove quotes?

Comment: Well, strings will always be in quotes, so the only way to remove quotes is to convert `'1'` to an integer

Answer (score 0):

You must convert values to `int` like this

```
d2 = {k: int(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

and save `d2` dict.

Comment: I've found a better solution, I will use a simple standard write to file. Using string and avoiding dictionary.

Comment: Nice, you asked how to get rid of quotes not for better solution.